# ファイルから同じワークスペースにある別フォルダを認識させる方法はありますか？

Tags: html, vscode

以下のように VS Code のワークスペースに2つのフォルダを追加したとき，

```
workspace
- - - - -
 ├ project
 │  └ sample.html
 └ img
    └ sample.png
```

sample.htmlに，imgフォルダがあたかもprojectフォルダ下にあるかのように認識させて以下のようにimgフォルダ内のファイルにアスセスできるようにしたいです．

```html
<img src=="img/sample.png">
```

このようなワークスペース設定はありますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

できません。エディターの設定が HTML の意味論に影響を与えるべきではありません。同じ内容の HTML ファイルでも個々人が違う設定のエディターで扱う可能性がありますし、Web ブラウザーはエディターとは関係なく HTML ファイルをページにレンダリングします。

一旦エディターのことは忘れて Web の機能やファイルシステムの機能を使ってやりたいことができないか模索し、その後その設定をエディターに反映できないか考える方が筋が良さそうです。もしそれに際して疑問があれば、作っているページの構成と実現したいことを説明する新しい質問をご投稿ください。